# Is there a UI Exerciser for iOS like Monkey on Android?

Tags: ios, testing, ios-ui-automation

I'm looking for a development tool that will allow me to send randomly generated user inputs (touches, hardkeys, gestures) to an iOS devices (not simulator) like [Monkey](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/monkey.html) on Android.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The UI Automation instrument in Instruments allows you to script interaction with your user interface, taking screenshots or testing for valid responses along the way.  These testing scripts are written in JavaScript, which lets you run fairly complex tests.

The tests I've run have always been directed, but I don't see a reason why you couldn't use something like a random() function to trigger randomly placed touch events, etc.  From this, you could build your own custom Monkey-like tool for hammering on your application.  Even better, you could run other instruments at the same time as this one to identify potential memory leaks or CPU hotspots.

I show how UI Automation works as part of the Testing session in [my course on iTunes U](http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewPodcast?id=407243028), for which my notes can be viewed [here](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/sites/default/files/Fall2010CourseNotes/ui%20automation.html).

Comment: Thanks! It took some (not much) work and does what I need it to.